# How to Identify Bus Stops Using just GPS Data?

Tags: gps, data-analysis, vehicle-routing

I'm trying to identify bus stops using GPS dataset including those attributes:

- Bus Number
- Current Bus Latitude
- Current Bus Longitude
- Current Time Recorded

I grouped data by bus_no and date and I did calculation on the data to get distance, duration, speed, and each stop occurred with its duration until a move happen. Now I want to identify bus stop from these set of stops occurred some of these stops occurred because of a traffic or because it's a bus stop and I want to identify this so is it a way to do it ?
I tried to read papers on this problem but I didn't find any thing that like this. most of papers already have stops determined.

So is there anyone can give me an advice for how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between a bus stop and a traffic stop  in your situation is the **duration of the stop**. 
 Bus stops duration would be consistent and short, rather than long and inconsistent like a traffic stop, hence I would advise you to create small bins of duration and plot a **histogram**. 
 Ideally, the highest bin would be your bus stop duration, then you can map the duration bin back to the stops.

Comment: I think duration isn't it; maybe even statistics won't help: If there's a periodic traffic light, the bus may stop frequently there. OTOH on a non-occupied bus stop the bus may pass by occasionally.